# issue with urlencode in browsers view (php/html)

Tags: php, url

I want encode my urls in my webpage...

I use this method:

```
<a  href="<?php echo urlencode('http://www.example.com/dir dir'); ?>"
```

but in output in browsers the address change to this:

> ```
> http://www.example.com/http://www.example.com/dir dir
> ```

how can I use urlencode to avoid that problem

Comment: Look `urlencode('http://www.example.com/dir dir')` result: `href="http%3A%2F%2Fwww.example.com%2Fdir+dir`. I hope you understand

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```html
<a  href="<?php echo 'http://www.example.com/', urlencode('dir'); ?>"
```

look for manual [php urlencode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.urlencode.php)